# awk文に関しての質問です。

Tags: linux

例

```
7月1日　7月2日 7月3日　... 9月30日
10000   10000 20000       13000
```

上記のようなファイルがあると仮定します。

これらを7月1日から7月3日までを足し合わせ、それらを半永久的に数値があるだけ繰り返すにはどうしたらよいでしょうか？

```
7月1日　7月2日 7月3日　
10000   10000 20000   
↓
7月1~3日 7月2~4日　7月3~日
40000　　　・・・　　・・・
```

こんな感じのイメージです。

Comment: 1日ごとに続く後ろ2日をあわせた「3日分」を計算していく、ということでしょうか。数値だけならやりようがありそうですが、日付部分（文字列）も処理が必要なら手間がかかりそうです。あと、最終日（例だと9月30日）の扱いはどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　タイトルが「awk文に関しての質問です」となっていますが、こちら awk で実現したいということでしょうか？　ご質問の内容を見るに、何でも良いのでシェルスクリプト等を用いてこの処理を実現したいように思いました。「データを3日ごとに足し合わせたい」「awkを使って3日後までの合計を求めたい」など、質問者さんが解決したい問題を具体的に表すタイトルに変えて頂けると幸いです。また、もし質問者さんが既に試してみた方法があれば、動かなくても良いのでそちらを追記して頂けると、質問者さんのお悩みがより詳細に理解でき回答しやすいです。質問文下の「編集」から自由に編集できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

入力データのカラムの区切り文字がよく分からないので、スペースやタブ文字の連続と仮定して、出力はタブ区切りにしています。

```c
awk -F '[ \t]+|月|日[ \t]*' -vOFS='\t' '
  NR==1{
    idx=0
    for(i=1;i<=(NF-5);i+=2){
      idx++
      if($i==$(i+4)){
        $idx = $i"月"$(i+1)"〜"$(i+5)"日"
      } else {
        $idx = $i"月"$(i+1)"日〜"$(i+4)"月"$(i+5)"日"
      }
    }
    NF=idx;print
  }
  NR==2{
    for(i=1;i<=(NF-2);i++){
      $i = $i + $(i+1) + $(i+2)
    }
    NF=idx;print
  }
' data.txt
```

月が変わる場合は開始と終了の日付全体を出力します。

```c
... 7月29〜31日 7月30日〜8月1日 7月31日〜8月2日 8月1〜3日 ...
```